# Open URL via proxy using JS

Tags: javascript

I would like to open a link using a proxy in JavaScript, my idea is to somehow generate a link that would use one of available proxies. What I do is:

```
window.open("http://url");
```

How to alter URL to add a proxy to it? Any othe ideas welcome, I never had anything to do with proxies so don't mind if is a silly question.

Comment: What do you mean you want to add a proxy to the url? Do you mean you want to direct the browser to a host address that's directing traffic to another host address? Can you define exactly what you mean by proxy here?

Comment: What I need is some Youtube views, I have a simple script that opens a new browser tab, but I would like to use other IPs than my PC